# Get unique id for household in Alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to create a skill which is persistent between several users within an household.
For example, if user A says something, save it to the DB so user B (within the same household) can query it.
Is there a unique ID for that?

A solution I thought about is asking the users for an household name and use it along with some global incremental int as primary key?

Answer (score 0):

You could have multiple skills, each with a different activation name, but linked on your backend to the same account.  By using the different skills, the user is identified.

This is how I handle my personal household skill to distinguish between my preferences and my wife's.

From a commercial perspective, you'll need a name or set of names that make sense as a group and your brand.

Comment: I do need it for "commercial" (or at least public)  
I thought about providing some "key" so other users may use it to identify themselves, I'm not sure how much of a "good practice" this is for a skill.